# #target photoshop doesn't find Photoshop CC

Tags: target, photoshop-script

I installed Photoshop CC 2015 on my Mac airbook with the result that my javascripts for photoshop show an error message  'app.bringToFront is not a function'.

The scripts start with:

## target photoshop

app.bringToFront()

On my iMac the scripts are running without any problem in Phoroshop CC.

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong on my laptop/library/application support?

$.writeln(app) returns 'ExtendScript Toolkit'.

Thanks for any help

Hans

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your scripts? If you're running those from ESTK, change the target app from ESTK to PS. If you're running them from File menu, you don't need to target photoshop in the script